# Docker desktop-windows error on builder settings

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-desktop

I'm tyring to use docker desktop-windows but it gaves me error

`request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2FdockerDesktopWindowsEngine/_ping, check if the server supports the requested API version`

desktop-linux works fine but I need to work on win.

I have ASP.NET Core Web API with docker. First it gaves error 'change docker desktop-windows' than docker  And can not run docker desktop. I reinstall docker but still same problem. How can i fix it?

I am using Windows 10. Docker Desktop version 4.27.2

Answer (score 0):

1. Sure you did not update accidentally to 4.27.**3** or later? I got exactly your problem, after I installed the 4.28.0 Version - see below...
2. You need Hyper-V enabled for this: is it working correctly on your machine? If you are using Windows Home Edition there is no chance: upgrade your Windows to Professional Edition - see maybe [docker-for-windows](/questions/tagged/docker-for-windows)?

From my view, at this time the Docker Desktop (at least Version 4.28.0) seems to have a problem with some current Windows 10 setups, updates and things ...

After I de-installed the 4.28.0 and replaced it with a fresh install of the Docker Desktop Version 4.27.2 (see [Docker Desktop release notes](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4272)) everything works fine for me with VS 2022 and ASP.NET 8.
... don't Update DD until this is fixed! ;)

The same error message seems to occur with linux containers too ([desktop-linux-builder error in windows desktop app](https://forums.docker.com/t/desktop-linux-builder-error-in-windows-desktop-app/139164/1), which leads to [GitHub, docker/for-win: ERROR: request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version...](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13909)) - there is a hint upgrading the WSL2 which might help too, if it is not updated regularly with Windows (see here: https://superuser.com/questions/1709437/how-can-i-update-the-kernel-in-wsl2-kernel-to-latest-release).